# Generate prototype classes from orginal class files in PHP

Tags: php, class, parsing

Is there any way in PHP to read a php source file which contains one or more classes and then create a prototype class (similar to interface)

**Original class looks like this:**

```
class Math {

    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function set_a($a) {
        $this -> a = $a;
    }

    public function set_b($b) {
        $this -> b = $b;
    }

    public function sum() {
        return $a + $b;
    }

}
```

**The prototype file must look like this:**

```
class Math {

    public function set_a($a) { }

    public function set_b($b) { }

    public function sum() { }

}
```

I want to do this dynamically by reading the class files at runtime and generating prototype classes. Is there any library in PHP through which I can read class meta information from file without including.

**EDIT**: I need to create a PHP file listing all prototype classes. The reason is that I have created a PHAR file for my library. And whenever I need to use any code from within the PHAR file i just include it using the following syntax.

```
require_once("phar://mylibrary.phar/math.php");
```

But the **problem is that the code hints and intelli-sense does not work.** I am using zend studio. So I thought, if I create a single file with all prototype classes and then include into new project then code hinting will work.

Comment: Why you want to do it?

Comment: You could use PHPs [tokenizer abilities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your coding style guarantees that you'll never break the arguments of a function declaration over multiple lines, you can hack a prototype generator pretty easily by selecting lines that match the following patterns (and correcting the braces as needed):

```
/^class /
/^}/
/^\s*(\w+)?\s*function\b/   # Must append a closing } to each line matching this
```

You could rig a PHP script to do all this, but if you've got the Unix tools in your environment, the above is a few characters away from being a complete sed script.

Here it is embedded in a PHP script, as requested (not tested):

```
$fp = fopen("source.php");
while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
    if (preg_match("/^class |^}/", $line))
        print $line;
    elif (preg_match('/^\s*(\w+)?\s*function\b/', $line))
        print rtrim($line) . " }\n";
}
```

Adapt/extend as needed for your coding style.

Comment: This is very unflexible and bound to assumptions. I don't think this is the right approach with regex.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I agree that a working solution based on a real PHP parser would be preferable, but I don't see one on offer: the tokenizer you mention doesn't even come close. Are you suggesting the OP write a PHP parser from scratch? The goal is just to generate code hints, so "bound to assumptions" is a hell of a lot better than nothing.

Comment: PS. I did say "hack a prototype generator".

Comment: No I'm not suggesting he/she should write a PHP parser from scratch. But with the tokenizer you can easily avoid matching strings and other funny situations. You can do a pretty basic scanner with a few lines, as seen in the [examples section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php)

Comment: Can you modify the code and use this expression in preg_match function?

Comment: +1 I have tested it and works great. Very good idea. I will further refine it according to my needs. Thanks

Comment: Glad you like it! Watch out for commented-out lines, and for `protected static` functions and the like (only one modifier supported by the current RE above).